# I am using a Visa card, I lived overseas, can I have the information about my visa being evaluated to have my USA credit score increased?

Tags: italy

I am using for many years, aVisa card issued in Italy since I lived overseas, can I have the informations about my visa card and payments,  being evaluated, to have my USA credit score increased?
In Italy is not in use to give a credit score. The banks keep the customers information on computer, to know if a person is a good payer or not.

Answer (score 1):

An American credit rating (FICO) is created by the reporting agencies (TransUnion, Experian) based on information provided to them by American financial entities. Foreign accounts are not reported to the agencies so they have no effect on a USA credit score. Some international banks will consider your foreign credit history with them as a basis for them to establish an initial US credit account, which will then allow you to start building a USA credit score (FICO). I'm sure there are others, but [Citi seems to have such a program](https://online.citi.com/US/JRS/pands/detail.do?ID=MovingtoUS).

TL;DR: No, your foreign credit history is irrelevant to a USA credit score, but it may assist you in establishing a USA FICO score depending on your bank.